# Do I need to create JSP in spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am new in spring security and I have several question on this topic.

Can I use regular html files or I need to create jsp file for the login page ?

and if I don't want to create form but only few fields is it ok ?

This is my HTML in JS

```
createContent: function(controller){


    this.emailInput = new sap.m.Input('emailInput', {
         liveChange: function(event) {

        }
    })

    var passwordInput = new sap.m.Input('passwordInput', {
        type: 'Password',
        liveChange: function(event) {

        }
    });


    return layout;
},
```

this is the controller

```
       $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: SERVER_URL + '/login',
            data : 'j_username=' + myUserName + '&j_password='+ myPassword,
            success: function(result) {

                ...
               }
              })
```

this is the servelet

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping("/login")
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public class AuthenticationController {



@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String login(@RequestParam(value="j_username", required=true) String email,
                    @RequestParam(value="j_password", required=true) String password)
{


    try {    
            ....do logic and create  resultList
            return gson.toJson(resultList);


    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return e.toString();
    }
    finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple HTML for login page as well. Ultimate aim is to call post service (bydefault /j_spring_security_check) from client page (html or jsp), as long as this is valid, you may call from any extension.

Comment: what do you mean to bydefault /j_spring_security_check ?

Comment: I want that the login page will be html file and not jsp file

Comment: when you configure form-login with spring-security, by default, it maps /j_spring_security_check post service to authenticate.

Comment: can we have short chat ?

Comment: if I have UI without form but only few input fields and button is it ok or Do I need to create form ?

Comment: It's fine, in that case u can use Ajax post request to authenticate

Comment: my html file are wrote in JS and not in html is it a problem ? do I need to add this logic of InternalResourceViewResolver to move between pages ?

Comment: Can u pls attach snippet here, i will help

Comment: can we have short chat ?

Comment: I will add if we can't have chat

Comment: I added my code the HTML js , the controller and the servlet